# react router did not work, error decoder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

What's wrong with below code? I just want to navigate to page B from page A where page A has a link. I don't want to use any layout aka container. I got this error after follow the error link the console :

```
_registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

My code:

```
var { Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link, browserHistory } = ReactRouter

const UserProfile = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <p>James</p>
        <p>age:20</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

const App = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <h1>Home page</h1>
            <div><Link to="/profile/1">Go</Link></div>
          </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/profile/:id" component={UserProfile}/>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('App')
);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpgGgL?editors=0010

Comment: Can you post your html page? are you sure you have a `<div/>` with an Id of `"App"`?

Comment: document.getElementById('app') your mistake is that you should have been written "app" instead of App

Answer (score 0):

As @Ruben Karapetyan already wrote in his comment, you have a typo in `document.getElementById('App')`. Instead of `App` you have `app` written in your HTML code. Therefore, you have to write `document.getElementById('app')`.